# REST API option not available in InfoPath 2013 Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, wcf-rest

I want to call custom my REST WCF service deployed in SharePoint ISAPI (_vti_bin) folder from within an InfoPath form that was migrated from SharePoint 2007. The form opens just fine in InfoPath Designer but the REST API option is not available to me for some reason. It seems its disabled from somewhere.

[Image-Link: InfoPath Designer - REST API data source option not avialble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGzCB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try select "From Web Service" in the Ribbon:

[image]

It will open Rest API Connection Wizard:

[image]